# Writing multiline equation in align environment -> integrals become smaller?

Tags: align, amsmath, multirow, integral

My goal is to reproduce the following math snippet. The problem is not the many symbols but the fact that when I use the `align` environment, the integral sign becomes small, which results in less 'visual pleasure'.

[image]

What I tried:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div} 
\begin{document}

Then,

\begin{align}
\sup_{v \in L^2}\dfrac{\int_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)}  &\ge  \sup_{v \in D}\dfrac{\int_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)} \ge  \sup_{v \in D, \Psi(v) < \infty}\dfrac{\int_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)} \\
 &\ge \sup_{z \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega, \R^n)}\dfrac{-\int_{\Omega}u\Div(z) \,\mathrm{d}x}{\|z \|_{\infty}} \ge J(u).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

Please ignore the two slight differences in letters.

Basically, what I am looking for, I guess, is something like `\dfrac` but for integrals?

Comment: `\displaystyle\int`.  FYI, `\dfrac` is essentially `\displaystyle\frac`.

Comment: Off topic but: I think your formula will look much better if you do `\frac{1}{\Psi(u)} \int` and so on instead of having the integral inside the fraction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `\displaystyle`.  Thus, one can define

```
\newcommand\dint{\displaystyle\int}
```

to achieve what you want with `\dint`.

As David notes in a comment, *`\dint` will make everything following the integral display style not just the integral.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div} 
\newcommand\dint{\displaystyle\int}
\begin{document}
Then,
\begin{align}
\sup_{v \in L^2}\dfrac{\dint_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)}  &\ge  \sup_{v \in D}\dfrac{\dint_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)} \ge  \sup_{v \in D, \Psi(v) < \infty}\dfrac{\dint_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)} \\
 &\ge \sup_{z \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega, \R^n)}\dfrac{-\dint_{\Omega}u\Div(z) \,\mathrm{d}x}{\|z \|_{\infty}} \ge J(u).
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was a super quick answer! Thanks!

Comment: note `\dint` will make everything following the integral display style not just the integral

Comment: Don't leave a blank line before `\begin{align}` if you don't want to get zapped by @egreg... :-)

Comment: :^) @Mico You are so right...I wasn't even looking at that.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of inserting a number of `\displaystyle` directives ahead of `\int` statements in the denominators of various fractions, one could define a variant form of `\frac` called, say, `\ddfrac` -- short for "double displaystyle frac", I suppose. That way, you would be doing more semantic mark-up and less visual formatting.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}

\begin{document}

Then, % <-- don't leave a blank line before '\begin{align}'
\begin{align}
 \sup_{v \in L^2}  \ddfrac{\int_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)}  
 &\ge \sup_{v\in D}\ddfrac{\int_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)} 
  \ge \sup_{v\in D,\Psi(v)<\infty}\ddfrac{\int_{\Omega}uv \,\mathrm{d}x}{\Psi(u)} \\
 &\ge \sup_{z\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega, \R^n)}
  \ddfrac{-\int_{\Omega}u\Div(z) \,\mathrm{d}x}{\norm{z}_{\infty}} \ge J(u).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```